# Is there a way to make a button with link to powerpoint file open with office online?

Tags: office365, ms-office, powerpoint

I'd like to be able to have a button with a link or data-element with a ppt or pptx file, and when clicking, instead of downloading, the button opens the powerpoint in a new window of Office/Powerpoint online (the web version of powerpoint).

I've looked throughout the office docs and can only find things for add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the presentation in PowerPoint Online, creating a Share link, then setting that URL in a hyperlinked shape in PowerPoint. It's working here, though you do have to sign in to OneDrive.

Comment: Nope. I'm looking for something quick and dynamic to be on over 1000 pages that hae powerpoint links.

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write a macro for you? That's not a service of this site.

Comment: No obviously not I wanna know if this is a possible thing or not. Not writing me a macro but if there is a tool that has this sort of functionality I can run ppt links through.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with a VBA macro. I'm not aware of any add-in that does this.